# Application Insights in IHostedService console application

Tags: .net-core, console-application, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am trying to enable Application Insights in a console application using `IHostedService` (for the moment, it's a simple console application which we run as WebJob, in future in containers).

As far as my knowledge goes, in the following code, so far we do not have any extension to register globally Application Insights as an implementation of **`ILogger`**:

```
  public static class Program
    {
        public static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
                {
                    config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
                {
                    logging.AddConfiguration(context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

                    if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        logging.AddConsole();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //TODO: register ApplicationInsights
                    }
                });

            return hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync();
        }
    }
```

So far, I found out that potentially, I should be able to set everything up using custom implementation of the logger, i.e. `public class ApplicationInsightsLogger : ILogger`, and then... register it in the container so that DI resolves it.

Is this the right direction?

Comment: why not integrate the ILogger with application insights? you can do it easily by adding app-insight package.

Comment: Yes, so right now, we've prepared an overload of ILogger to use `AppInsights` + `LoggerProvider` registered in container. But that's not very elegant considering we have some of this functionality in `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web`. The problem is, that what we need is in this library but it's not abstracted yet to a separate package for `GenericHost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an extension that I could use from either an `IHost` or an `IWebHost`:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights;

public static class LoggingBuilderExtensions
{
    public static ILoggingBuilder AddLogging(this ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
    {
        loggingBuilder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace);
        loggingBuilder.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
        loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights();
        return loggingBuilder;
    }
}
```

Since I'm not sending in the context (`HostBuilderContext` or `WebHostBuilderContext`), I can use it in either app type like this:

`new HostBuilder().ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddLogging())`

or

`WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddLogging())`

If you needed a specific property from the context (like environment type), you could extract that and send it in as a parameter to the extension.

Here's a reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-logging/blob/develop/src/ILogger/Readme.md

Comment: This is good, I will check this in the nearest future. Since I initially dropped the message, the impl has evolved a little. Now it might not be even a problem. Microsoft's docs are better as well. Thank you.